# linq and json, anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, jqgrid

i have a json which is this:

```
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = reservations.Select(x => new { x.ReservationId, x.Employee.Name,roomName = x.Room.Name, x.Date, x.StartTime, x.EndTime, x.Notes}).ToList()
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.ReservationId,
                    cell = new string[]
                    {
                    roomName,
                    x.Name,
                    x.Date.ToString().Split(' ')[0],
                    x.StartTime.ToString().Remove(5) +" - " +x.EndTime.ToString().Remove(5),
                    x.Notes,
                    String.Format("<input type=\"button\" value=\"DETAILS\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/Reservation/Details/{0}'\"/>&nbsp &nbsp<input type=\"button\" value=\"EDIT\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/Reservation/Edit/{0}'\"/>&nbsp &nbsp<input type=\"button\" value=\"DELETE\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/Reservation/Delete/{0}'\"/>", x.ReservationId), 
                    }
                }).ToArray(),
        };
```

this json will be returned to a jqGrid. when i typed x.Room.Name in the first select statement, an error occured because a property with the same name already exists (i.e. x.Employee.Name).

so i tried "roomName=x.Room.Name" and i put roomName in the cell content.

however, when the json is returned to my jqGrid, the column, which supposedly contains the roomName, is empty. how could i show the values of x.Room.Name in other ways?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but maybe this would work?  x => new { x.ReservationId, new { x.Employee.Name }, new { x.Room.Name } }

Comment: probably you used Entity Framework and have forgot to use `Include` to fill the `Room` part (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx#sectionSection0) for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have renamed the column to `roomName` make sure that on the client you have a corresponding column:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    colNames: [ 'roomName', 'Name', ..... other columns ],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'roomName', index: 'roomName' },
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name' },
        .....
    ],
    ........
});
```

Comment: It will be used the data for the row as `cell = new string[]`. One post unnamed data for row of data. So I think the name of column is not the origin on the problem which **eaon21** has. I suppose that JSON response from the server has already empty `roomName` column.